# Why IDEA can't recognize the Spark jar file?

Tags: intellij-idea, jar, apache-spark

I've downloaded the source code of Spark, extract it and build it according to the official document as follows:

```
wget http://ftp.tc.edu.tw/pub/Apache/spark/spark-1.2.0/spark-1.2.0.tgz .
tar xzf spark-1.2.0.tgz
cd spark-1.2.0
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.2 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package
```

Finally I transfer the assembly jar file to local:

```
scp root@host:/home/workspace/spark-1.2.0/assembly/target/scala-2.11/spark-assembly-1.2.0-hadoop2.2.0.jar ~
```

I intend to import this jar file into my project in Intellij Idea, but this jar cannot be recognized by the IDE, and an error has be thrown: **'IDEA cannot determine what kind of files the chosen items contain. Choose the appropriate categories from the list.'**, which is shown in the following graph:

[image: Error when import jar in Intellij Idea]

The bad thing is that there are many grammar error in my edit windows which are all related to Spark package and Hadoop package, whereas the project can build successfully in this scenario regardless of the grammar error mentioned above.

**P.S.**

1. I'm 100% sure that some of my other jar files (e.g. in .m2 directory) can be imported normally without the aforementioned error/warning.
2. If I import the same jar file into Eclipse, it is recognized successfully. I've tested this jar both in IDEA-13 and IDEA-14, which all fails.
3. Viewing the content of this jar via `jar -tf XXX.jar` works normally.
4. After adding this problematic .jar file into my project, I can't even view the content of the jar file.
   [image: cant_view_jar_content]

   This is what a normal .jar file looks like:
   [image: normal_jar_file]

I've uploaded this jar in [BaiDu_YunFile](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1i3BZ80X), Could anyone give me some idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This message is not an error, it's a question that the IDE asks you. Have you tried answering it?

Comment: Of course, I've choosed classes, and as I said, There're lots of grammar error and can be built successfully. @yole

Comment: What is the contents of this .jar file? You can see it in the IntelliJ IDEA project view after you add it as a library.

Comment: Actually, if a jar file can be detected by IDEA, it will not ask me with the dialog, and the jar file's content can be extracted in the selected dialog. @yole

Comment: This is the point, I can't extract the content of .jar file in IDEA project view. I'll append this phenomenon in my question right now.@yole

Comment: Whats in the jar file, if you open it with winzip?

Comment: Similar strcture with a nomalr .jar file. @vikingsteve

Comment: Ok, so a path structure that looks like a package, with `.class` files insied? any `META-INF` ? Please be more precise

Comment: With .class files and META-INF. As is said in the question, this jar file can be imported into Eclipse successfully (No grammar error and compile normally) @vikingsteve

Comment: I've uploaded the jar file to the Internet, could you try to download it and give ti a shot? Thanks in advance! @vikingsteve

Comment: From home tonight I can, in about 7 hours from now - if that helps.

Comment: Pardon for the location of server is in China :] @vikingsteve

Comment: I met the save problem. Have you got any solution?

Comment: Extract the spark.jar file via 'Archive Expert', then bundle it to another spark_2.jar file. Import both the two *.jar files into IDEA will just do the trick, though a bit tricky. @DANGFan

Answer (score 1):

Check the jdk version (**Perfrence-->About Intellij IDEA**) which the Intellij IDEA used. If the version is too low, it cannot parse the jar properly. If you use the mac IDEA, just update the jvm version to 1.7 or newer in the info.plist of the IDEA contents folder.

Comment: Mine is JDK1.7 and IDEA_14

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with another jar file (libsvm.jar). By downloading the source code from GitHub and calling the make command, the .jar file was recreated and I did not have any issue any more. So I guess the jar file was probably created with some incompatible version of Java.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today while using the assembly jar provided by the Spark 1.5.0 installed through brew. Then I found I have a 1.4.1 version on my laptop, which has `spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar`. When I use this jar file in IntelliJ, it was successfully recognized and all the grammar errors are gone.